# Bot framework + qna maker : Method not found exception

Tags: botframework

I am using Visual studio 2017 with Bot framework 3.8.1. Created simple QnA Maker dialog using with cognitive services 1.1.0.
QnA maker is working fine, I have tested it online. However when I test the bot which triggers QnA maker I get following exception :

> Exception: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.PromptOptions1..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList1, Int32, Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.PromptStyler, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList`1)'.",

This works well when I develop using Visual Studio 2015.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known issue due to the latest updates done on BotBuilder SDK. It was reported [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/issues/28). To unblock yourself you can just re-compile the library using the latest version of BotBuilder, that will make the trick.